# I'm trying to write certain bits of a register hi to initiate power mode into sleep

Tags: c, nios, sata

My issue is I read the value of ADI_DEV_CORE_STATUS it remains as 0x2A, even after I write assert a 1 on bit 22 to enable power mode requests, and i print out the value directly after the value doesn't change.

I'm trying send a a request to go to slumber mode,

In the ADI DEV CORE STATUS register,

bit 26 is defined as power mode fail (read only),

bit 25 is defined as Core in sleep (read only),

bit 24 is defined as a power mode request for partial slumber (read/write),

bit 23 is defined as a power mode request for slumber mode(read/write),

bit 22 is defined as enables Host Initiated Power Mode requests(read/write),

bit 21 is defined as initiates the sending of COMWAKE Burst pattern to wake up from slumber (read/write)

bit 5 is defined as Phy-Ready (read only),

bit 4 is defined as Reset (read/write),

bit 3 is defined as indicates device state machine is in Idle(read only),

bits[2:0] are defined as Current interface speed(0h: No connection)(1h:Gen1 rate established)(2:h: Gen 2 rate established)(3h: Gen3 rate established)(other values reserved for future generations)

other values defined in code

```
u32 read;
u32 write;
u32 mask;
u32 rc;
/*Device Application Status (DevCoreStatus Register 0x002C)*/
DEV_STATUS_SIM        = (1 << 31), /*Core in Simulation*/
DEV_STATUS_PM_FAIL    = (1 << 26), /*Power Mode Fail*/
DEV_STATUS_CORE_SLEEP = (1 << 25), /*Successful Transition into Sleep Mode*/
DEV_STATUS_PARTIAL_GO = (1 << 24), /*Power Mode Request for Partial Mode*/
DEV_STATUS_SLUMBER_GO = (1 << 23), /*Power Mode Request for Slumber Mode*/
DEV_STATUS_EN_PWDN    = (1 << 22), /*Enables Host Initiated Power Mode Requests*/
DEV_STATUS_COMWAKE    = (1 << 21), /*Initiates the Sending of COMWAKE Burst Pattern to Allow for Waking up from Slumber*/
DEV_STATUS_PHYRDY     = (1 << 5), /*Indicates the Device Core has Achieved a Phy-Ready State*/
DEV_STATUS_RESET      = (1 << 4), /*Upon Exit From Reset, Device will Send a COMINIT*/
DEV_STATUS_DEVIDL     = (1 << 3), /*Device State Machine is in Idle*/
DEV_STATUS_SPEED_0    = (0x0 << 0), /*0h: No Connection to the Host Established*/
DEV_STATUS_SPEED_1    = (0x1 << 0), /*1h: Gen 1 Communication Established*/
DEV_STATUS_SPEED_2    = (0x2 << 0), /*2h: Gen 2 Communication Established*/
DEV_STATUS_SPEED_3    = (0x3 << 0), /*3h: Gen 3 Communication Established*/

struct DevDesc {
  u32 * mmio; //memory mapped io address
  u32 qd_cmd; //queued command - doesnt appear to be used yet. guessing active-high 32 bits
  u8 phy_rdy; //phy_rdy flag - set by software
  u8 spd_allowed; //same as below. doesnt appear to be used yet
  u8 cur_lnk_spd; /* 00 -> Not phyrdy, 01 -> Gen1 -> 02 -> Gen2, 03-> Gen3*/
  u8 dev_mode; /* DEV_MODE_xxx, eg SATA, SAS, dual */
  struct ata_port_operations *ops; //what is this? doesnt appear to be used
};

struct MemDesc {
  u32 * non_qd_dev_mem_addr;
  u32 non_qd_dev_mem_span;
  u32 * qd_dev_mem_addr;
  u32 qd_dev_mem_span;
  u32 * sg_addr;
  u32 sg_span;
};

struct MemDesc mem_desc_g = {
  .non_qd_dev_mem_addr = (u32*)(DEV_PORT_MEMORY_BASE), //Non-queued command memory. base=0x40000
  .non_qd_dev_mem_span = DEV_PORT_MEMORY_SPAN, //65536 bytes - 0x40000:0x4FFFF
  .qd_dev_mem_addr = (u32*)(DATA_BUFFER_BASE_ADDRESS), //Queued command buffer. base=0x50000.
  .qd_dev_mem_span = DATA_BUFFER_SPAN, //65536 bytes - 0x50000:0x5FFFF
  .sg_addr = (u32*)(DEV_SG_MEMORY_BASE), //Scatter-gather list. base=0x60000
  .sg_span = DEV_SG_MEMORY_SPAN, //65536 bytes - 0x60000:0x6FFFF
};

//System descriptor
//Points to components
struct SysDesc sys_desc_g = {
  .dd = &dev_desc, //device core descriptor
  .md = &mem_desc_g, //memory structure descriptor
};

u32 RegRead32(u32* BaseAddr, u32 Offset)
{
  u32 temp;
  temp = (u32)BaseAddr + Offset;
  return *(volatile int *)temp;
}

void RegWrite32(u32* BaseAddr, u32 Offset, u32 WriteData)
{
  u32 temp;
  temp = (u32)BaseAddr + Offset;
  *(volatile int *)temp = WriteData;
  return;
}

u32 wait_reg( u32* reg_addr, u32 mask, u32 val, u32 interval_usec, u32 timeout_usec)
{
  u32 ii = 0;
  u32 rc = 0;
  for(ii=0;ii<(timeout_usec/interval_usec); ii++){
  rc = RegRead32(reg_addr, 0);
  if((rc & mask) != val){
    return rc;
}
  //branch slot pad...
  RegRead32(reg_addr, 0);
  usleep(interval_usec);
}
//iprop_printf("%s:: wait reg timout. ending register value == %08X\n\r",__func__,rc);
return rc;
}


u32 power_mode_sleep (struct SysDesc * sd)
{
  rc = RegRead32((u32*)DEV_BUS_SLAVE_BASE, ADI_OFFSET + ADI_DEV_CORE_STATUS);
  alt_printf("The value of ADI_DEV_CORE_STATUS is 1.) %x \n", rc); /*Should print out 0x2A, phy-ready, in idle, and Gen2 speed*/
  rc = rc & 0xFF3FFFFF;
  rc |= DEV_STATUS_EN_PWDN; //DEV_STATUS_EN_PWDN = (1<<22)
  RegWrite32((u32*)DEV_BUS_SLAVE_BASE, ADI_OFFSET + ADI_DEV_CORE_STATUS, rc);
  read = RegRead32((u32*)DEV_BUS_SLAVE_BASE, ADI_OFFSET + ADI_DEV_CORE_STATUS);
  alt_printf("The value of ADI_DEV_CORE_STATUS is 2.) %x \n", read);
  rc |= DEV_STATUS_SLUMBER_GO;
  RegWrite32((u32*)DEV_BUS_SLAVE_BASE, ADI_OFFSET + ADI_DEV_CORE_STATUS, rc);
  read = RegRead32((u32*)DEV_BUS_SLAVE_BASE, ADI_OFFSET + ADI_DEV_CORE_STATUS);
  alt_printf("The value of ADI_DEV_CORE_STATUS is 3.) %x \n", read);
  rc = wait_reg((u32*)(DEV_BUS_SLAVE_BASE + ADI_OFFSET + ADI_DEV_CORE_STATUS),
    0x2000000, // only look at bit 25.
    0x000000, // if bit-25 == 1, We're core in sleep
    1, // wait 1us between register reads
    100000); // ~100ms
  alt_printf("The value of ADI_DEV_CORE_STATUS is 4.) %x \n", rc); /**/
  read = RegRead32((u32*)DEV_BUS_SLAVE_BASE, ADI_OFFSET + ADI_DEV_CORE_STATUS);
  alt_printf("The value of ADI_DEV_CORE_STATUS is 5.) %x \n", read);

  if ((read & 0x2000000) == DEV_STATUS_CORE_SLEEP)
  {
    alt_printf("Successfully Transitioned into sleep mode.\n");
  }
  else if ((read & 0x4000000) == DEV_STATUS_PM_FAIL)
  {
    alt_printf("Unsuccessful Transition into sleep mode.\n");
  }
  else
    alt_printf("The value of ADI_DEV_CORE_STATUS is 6.) %x \n", rc);
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

All my alt_printf(The value is %x", read); print out 0x2a, I should be reading a 0x40002a when power modes are enabled, 0xC0002a  when power modes are enabled and i'm sending a power request for slumber mode and a 0x2000000 when core is in sleep.

Comment: All your bits are belong to bus.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, rewrite the messed up pointer arithmetic. I assume the Offset is in bytes and not in u32 words.

```
u32 RegRead32(u32* BaseAddr, u32 Offset)
{
  volatile u32 *temp = (volatile u32 *) ((char *) BaseAddr + Offset);
  return *temp;
}

void RegWrite32(u32* BaseAddr, u32 Offset, u32 WriteData)
{
  volatile u32 *temp = (volatile u32 *) ((char *) BaseAddr + Offset);
  *temp = WriteData;
  /* empty return at the end of a void function not needed */
}
```

Since you've #defined some constants, don't use their numeric values afterwards, because you might make a mistake. I.e. simply test

```
if (read & DEV_STATUS_CORE_SLEEP)
```

and the result will be true when the bit is set.

But most importantly, post a complete code sample (your code is missing some variable declarations and wait_reg()) and simplify your test-case as much as possible. Also post the expected output. You write to registers and read them several times, it's unclear which write fails.

Now, if the writes still don't stick, re-read the datasheet to make sure you're following the protocol the device expects. Also look for tech notes related about the device -- sometimes the hardware is buggy and doesn't operate accoring to the datasheet (I've had that problem with an ADI DSP in the past). If so, this would be a hardware problem, not a SO question.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I can post more code in the comments section, or I can just edit my code and add more into it. My expected outputs for my alt_printf statement are as follows:

1.) 0x2a //means phy0rdy, idle, gen 2 speeds

2.) 0x40002a //means power modes are enabled, phy-rdy, idle, gen 2 speed

3.) 0xC0002a //means slumber request, power modes enabled, phy-rdy, idle, gen 2 speed

3.) 0x2000000 //means core is in sleep, this is what I want to read

4.) 5.) & 6.) should all print 0x2000000 because i want the core in sleep

it has been printing 0x2a for all my print statements.

Comment: Just edit your original code to make it complete. I meant actual output, not expected output -- I can't tell which step doesn't match your expectations. And make sure you don't have any off-by-1 bit errors, that's why I suggested the rewrites.

Comment: Do you have an e-mail I can send you the files? I just have code in about 8 different files, and it would make this page very long. You can send me an email at wellscdl@gmail.com

Comment: Nah. Just make the functions you've posted complete (you're leaving out var declarations plus a function!) But honestly, if you follow my suggestions and you're STILL not reading what you've written in the register, it's not a programming question, it's a hardware issue and I doubt anyone here on SO can help you

Comment: I've edited my code, here on SO as well as on Nios II, right now I'm waiting for a compile so I can test my code on some hardware. I'll post back in a few mins with my results.